# Converting wstring to lower case

Tags: c++, string, utf-16

I want to convert `wstring` into lower case. I found that there are a lot of answer using locale info. Is there any function like `ToLower()` for `wstring` also?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/towlower

Comment: Note that "lower case" is an inherently locale-specific operation.  In Turkey, `towlower('I'L) != 'i'L` (the result is actually `'ı'`)

Comment: In fact, case transformations are a nightmare.  As noted in the link, lowercase 'Σ' is either 'σ' and 'ς' depending on the position in the word, and lowercase "SS" in German is either "ß" or "ss" - depending on the word ("MASSE" can either be "Maße" or "masse" depending on which homograph it is!).  See http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html for more gory details.

Answer (score 14):

`std::towlower` is the function you want, from `<cwtype>`. This header contains many functions for dealing with wide strings.

Example:

```
// Convert wstring to upper case
wstring wstrTest = L"I am a STL wstring";
transform(
  wstrTest.begin(), wstrTest.end(),
  wstrTest.begin(),
  towlower);
```

Comment: I don't think this can work correctly with code points that span multiple code units.

Comment: @user2079303 C++ (and C here) requires that any supported code point fits in a wchar_t. In other words, that is  only a problem on Windows. (The real problem is that case mapping is not 1:1 in code points and is context-dependent, as noted in other comments)

Comment: @Cubbi A windows problems is a problem to most cross platform programs :) But yeah, that is indeed not the only reason why transformation one code-unit at a time cannot work. The mapping algorithm must deal with the strings as a whole to work correctly.

Comment: `<cwtype>` didn't work for me, but `<cwctype>` worked.

Answer (score 5):

Hope that helps..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main ()
{

std::wstring str = L"THIS TEXT!";
std::wcout << "Lowercase of the string '" << str << "' is ";
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
std::wcout << "'" << str << "'\n";

return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Lowercase of the string 'THIS TEXT!' is 'this text!'
```

Comment: Works great with this method ta

Comment: This with <algorithm> I do not require BOOST. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is wrong and extremely dangerous. Using ::tolower on chars (!) is already dangerous, on wchars it's just asking for a crash. If the value of character passed to ::tolower is not representable as unsigned char and does not equal EOF, the behavior is undefined. It is because implementations can use lookup table of size [256]. If you pass there anything, that is greater than 255 (as wchars can be), it can simply crash.